# Angular Schematics - How to create files dynamically?

Tags: angular, angular-schematics

I am working on Angular Schematics.

I have created a project, where I am able to scaffold components, modules, services etc.

But, whatever files are created by schematics has to be pre-existing. For example, If I wish to create a component, there should be a file with below content.

```
    export class <%= classify(name) %>ContainerComponent{

}
```

What I need to do is, I want to be able to create such files dynamically, may be in factory function(which is entry point to schematics codes)

```
function entity(options: any): Rule {}
```

I am not sure if it is doable, if anyone can provide or lead to some info, that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: take a look to https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/total-guide-to-custom-angular-schematics-5c50cf90cdb4

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos If I may know, what is this matter you're talking about?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What is this about?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56685857/automapper-not-mapping-net-core-2-2

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My apologies, I didn't see any comments from you. Others came to conclusion which contradicted what I might have assumed. I didn't want to create any confusion for other users.